# Twitter Web Intents - Get follower screenname?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, webintents

I'm using Twitter Web Intents to check if someone follows me.
The problem now is; I am only getting my own screenname as callback in the event object.

```
twttr.events.bind('follow', function(event) {
    alert(event.data.user_id);
});
```

Is there any way to get the followers screenname, so I can store it in the database. I want to use this as kind of "request invite"-function.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user who performed the follow is not revealed through the web intents javascript events -- it would reveal personal information about the user currently on your site without that user explicitly granting your site/application access to that information.

The best way to track recent followers of an account is using the User Streams API to obtain the events in real time as they happen: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/user